# SQL's stored procedure multiple result into temp table

Tags: sql-server

**Is there any way to create single stored procedure, that returns N result set and inside SQL JOB separate those N results into N different temp tables?**

I've got four stored procedures and each of SP returns result set. (all results differs)

All of these SPs are used in single SQL job for reporting.
So far I declared four temp tables to held result of four stored procedures, but I'd like to have one store procedure with all results set and at the same time separate them inside SQL JOB.

edit: I need to separate results set into temp tables because I can change them easily into html tables to send via mail

edit2:I'd like to achieve something like

```
SELECT INTO #MyTempTable1,#MyTempTable2,#MyTempTable3 FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC DBNAME.dbo.ALLPROCEDURESINONE')
```

so the first result from procedure would be stored in #MyTempTable1 second result set would be in #MyTempTable2 ... etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove  functionality of one stored procedure into another. It depends about parameters and the amount of code reused.
eg

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1()
AS
BEGIN
  SP1 Your code here...
END

CREATE PROCEDURE SP2()
AS
BEGIN
  SP2 Your code here...
END
```

and just combine the 2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1()
AS
BEGIN
  SP1 Your code here...

  SP2 Your code here...
END
```

Comment: I've got SELECT * 
INTO #MyTempTable1
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC DBNAME.dbo.Sp1') How can I select INTO multiple temp tables using single procedure? __ I've edited question

Comment: I believe that TSQL only notices the first result in a multiple-set stored procedure. Could you not do the inserts within the stored procedure?

Comment: I didn't know that. I'm very thankfull for this information :) Yeah i can put procedures code inside job. That will do the job

Comment: Your welcome, I was going to suggest if you really wanted to play with multi-set outputs maybe look into CLR or C#.